# TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function in React Redux Class Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, extends

I am working with some legacy code moved into my new react product. Essentially I have a large grouping of widgets (a lot!) so my employer has asked me NOT to rewrite them but work with them.

I have a BaseWidget:

```
import { Select } from 'layout/containers'
export default class BaseWidget extends React.Component {
  onChange = e => {
    this.props.onChange({ target: { value: e } });
  };

  get operators() { return .... }

  get value() { return .... } 


  get options() {
    const { options } = this;
    return options;
  }

  render() {
    const multi = this.operators.includes('in');
    return (
      <div>
        <label>{this.props.label}</label>
        <Select
          value={this.value}
          onChange={this.onChange}
          options={this.options}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And I need an AutocompleteWidget which extends from BaseWidget:

```
import { getAutocompleteOptions } from 'options/modules/autocomplete';

class AutocompleteWidget extends BaseWidget {
  onChange = e => {
    this.props.onChange({ target: { value: e } });
  };

  get options() {
    return ['options0', 'options1', 'options2'];
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ autocomplete }) => {
  return {
    autocomplete,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
  bindActionCreators(
    {
      getAutocompleteOptions,
    },
    dispatch,
  );
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AutocompleteWidget);
```

I want to use AutocompleteWidget in a specific widget class let's say AssetWidget:

```
export default class AssetWidget extends AutocompleteWidget {
  get options() {
    return ['asset0', 'asset1', 'asset2'];
  }
}
```

But my issue is I get this thrown:

```
TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function
```

And the stack trace seems to point to when I try to extend AssetWidget from AutocompleteWidget.

My guess is: **modern React-Redux does not play well with class-based inheritance in React components or something with inheriting components that are connected to the redux store/state. Or I am forgetting something technical or conceptual when I transferred my company's old React widget code to this new React codebase.**

Looking at other posts: I don't seem to have any circular dependency that I see, and my React version is up-to-date.

I hate class-based React and I usually do everything in functions so I could be forgetting something critical.

Comment: btw I can get around it making AssetWidget have a render and return AutocompleteWidget but I'd like it to just extend the class if possible to keep it all in the same class-based structure for now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I extend a "connected" component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42774676/how-can-i-extend-a-connected-component)

Comment: @HMR no it doesn't sadly. it gave me my workaround for HOC.

Comment: I think the point was that you can't extend what `connect` returns so you could use the [hoc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45980376/1641941) to not repeat the map state and dispatch methods.

Comment: @HMR I actually had a UI user error just now and couldn't see the first response only the second one so I had an incomplete picture. Yes, seems like that's really the only way to play with these redux and inheritance. I went a different direction and just passed things from my "widget" into props instead, made these classes basically dumb components. In short, yes the post does answer my questions. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

They say to not make subclasses of React class components.  I guess this is why. So, instead, make one class component, and pass in the particulars as props.

So, you have BaseWidget, that's your foundation, that's The React Component Class, the only one.

Now, factor out all the characteristics you want to be different between your different 'subclasses'.  So you have a baseThing, an autocompleteThing which is a subclass, an asssetThing which is another subclass.  Make your class hierarchy of these Things which describe what's different.

Then, your BaseWidget takes a prop, 'thing', which is a subclass of baseThing.